# Parse the output of a script and process the last line only before printing

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a simple CLI tool asking for a master password, and printing a string `$USER $PASSWORD` only if the master password is correct.

#### How to reproduce?

**Here is a script just for demonstrating my use-case**, the real script is in fact a CLI tool on which I have no control:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "Enter master password: "
read -s password

echo

[ "$password" == "MasterPassword" ] && echo "user1 Passw0rd!"
```

Example of usage:

```sh
$ ./my-cli-tool
Enter master password: ********
user1 Passw0rd!
```

#### Issue

I don't want the password (`Passw0rd!`) to be printed on screen. I want to print only the user (`user1`), and just copy the password (`Passw0rd!`) to the clipboard (let's say with `xclip -sel clipboard`).

#### What I have tried?

If the first line (`Enter master password`) were not there, I would have done:

```sh
./my-cli-tool |
    while read -r USER PASSWORD
    do
        echo $USER
        echo -n $PASSWORD | xclip -sel clipboard
    done
```

But my issue is that I should type the master password when the prompt asks for, and so the first line is always printed. I have tried to run `./my-cli-tool | tail -1`: the prompt is not shown, although if I type the master password, it only prints `user1 Passw0rd!`, so I can do the command above to copy the password into the clipboard.

#### Question

Do you have any idea to:

- always show the prompt on screen for the master password
- only print the user
- copy the password to the clipboard

#### Expected output

Basically, I would like that kind of output:

```sh
$ ./my-cli-tool | solution
Enter master password: ********
user1
```

And have `Passw0rd!` copied into my clipboard.

Comment: I do not understand. So just `./my-cli-tool | sed "s/$PASSWORD/*****/"`? `./my-cli-tool | sed 2d`? `f the first line (Enter master password) were not there, I would have don` why is the first line an issue? Just omit first line then. `using POSIX-compliant...to the clipboard` you are limited to POSIX but you have xclip? Don't you have bash or perl or python? Anyway, create a fifo, spawn the command writing to that fifo, read first line from fifo, output it, and do what "you would have done" with that while loop for the second line from fifo.

Comment: Your `sed` commands will just hide the password or delete the 2nd line. Omitting the first line is not easy (at least for me), because I want that line printed to the user to type their master password. POSIX compliant is maybe overkill, I'll remove that requirement from my question. I'll also add an example of the output I want.

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate on your last sentence? *Anyway, create a fifo, spawn the command writing to that fifo, read first line from fifo, output it, and do what "you would have done"*. I am not an expert in shell (otherwise I won't have asked that question :D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simply modified your answer a little bit -

```sh
./my-cli-tool | {
    x=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
    while [ "$x" != : ]; do
        printf %c "$x";
        x=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)
    done
    printf %s ": "
    while read -r USER PASSWORD
    do
        echo $USER
        echo -n $PASSWORD | xclip -sel clipboard
    done
}
```

Lemme know if it works.

**EDIT:** Updated logic. Uses `dd`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the prompt "Enter master password: " is not printed to the user running the command, so your answer does not fully answer my question.

Comment: @norbjd Could you please try again? I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Before accepting your answer, could you please elaborate it a little bit? Why did you use `dd`? What represents the colon? Thanks again.

Comment: @norbj If this answer has solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. `dd` reads from stdin one-character-at-a-time so that we can stop reading as soon as `./my-cli-tool` emits the `:` character. In `printf %s ": "`, the `:` is because the last `dd` call has eaten up the colon, and the space is to make the prompt look better.